# Application of Liouville's Theorem

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f(z)$ be an entire function such that $$|f(z)|<\frac{1}{|\text{Im}(z)|},\qquad z\in\Bbb C-\Bbb R.$$ The question asked me to prove that $f(z)=0$. At least looking at it, it really seems to have an application of Liouville's theorem lurking around somewhere, but I haven't found it.

My thoughts first led me to think about doing this by contradiction and using Picard's little theorem. So, I've considered a strip containing the real axis (say of width $2$ for simplicity). This will imply the complement maps into the unit disk, which implies that this strip has to map almost everywhere else on the complex plane. Now, on the imaginary axis, I know that $f(z)$ will vanish as $z\to\infty$, and this seems like it might be useful. I'm sort of under the impression $f(z)$ might have an essential singularity at $\infty$, which would mean $f(1/z)$ has an essential singularity at $0$. Either way, it of course can't have a pole at $\infty$ because of $f(z)$ vanishing on the imaginary axis, and if it is a removable singularity, it must be $0$, which still gives the solution. Therefore, I think it must have something to do with $f(z)$ having an essential singularity at $\infty$.

I was hoping to combine this with the above inequality and deduce a contradiction, but I haven't thought of one yet.

Any hints or suggestions? I'm studying for a prelim. exam, so this isn't homework.

**Update:** So, in the spirit of searching methods using the essential singularity at $z=0$, we have $$\left|f\left(\frac{1}{z}\right)\right|\leq\frac{1}{\left|\text{Im}\left(\frac{1}{z}\right)\right|}=\frac{|z|^2}{|y|}.$$ Thus, for $|y|>1$, we have $$\left|f\left(\frac{1}{z}\right)\right|<|y|\left|f\left(\frac{1}{z}\right)\right|<|z|^2.$$ Thus, if I can show that $|f(1/z)|$ is a polynomial, we'll know it can't have an essential singularity at the origin, concluding my proof.

Comment: Do you know Jensen's inequality, the one for holomorphic functions (not for convex ones)? It's a corollary of [Jensen's formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%27s_formula) if you drop the sum over zeros. $$\log |f(a)|\le \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi} \log|f(a+re^{it})|\,dt$$

Comment: @user75064: Yes I know the inequality, but I am not quite sure how to apply it here.

Comment: Fix a real number $a$  (arbitrary) and let $r\to \infty$.

Comment: @user75064, no matter how large your circle is, there is always an arc with small imaginary part and there is no uniform bound on that arc.

Comment: @Sanchez Correct, but I don't need a uniform bound. See my answer below.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Let $w \in \mathbb{C}$ and let $R > |w|$.   We first bound the analytic function $(z^2 - R^2)f(z)$ on the circle $|z| = R$.

If $|z| = R$ and $\operatorname{Re}z \ge 0$, then

$$|(z- R)f(z)| \le \frac{|z - R|}{\operatorname{Im}z} = \sec \theta$$

where $\theta \in [0, \dfrac{\pi}{4}]$ so $|(z - R)f(z)| \le \sqrt{2}$.

For $\operatorname{Re} z \le 0$ and $|z| = R$, we have

$$|(z + R)f(z)| \le \sqrt{2}$$

Hence,

$$|(z^2 - R^2)f(z)| \le 3R$$

on $|z| = R$. By the maximum modulus principle the same bound holds in the interior of the disk $|z| \le R$ and so

$$|f(w)| \le \frac{3R}{|w^2 - R^2|}$$ 
Letting $R \to \infty$, we get the desired result.

Comment: Where does the $3R$ come from?

Comment: @Clayton, I was just wondering that myself.  A sharper bound is $2\sqrt{2} R$, since the point on $|z| = R$ farthest from $\pm R$ is $\mp R$ at a distance of $2R$.  It looks like this was rounded up to $3R$.

Comment: @Clayton $|z - R||z + R||f(z)| \le 2\sqrt{2}R$

Comment: Okay, I was wondering about that. Last question: Why is $\theta\in[0,\pi/4]$? I think I have a vague idea, just not 100% sure.

Comment: Nice answer! A little simplification of your argument: when $|z|=R$, $|z^2-R^2|=|z^2-z\bar{z}|=|z||z-\bar{z}|=2R|\mathrm{Im}(z)|$. @AntonioVargas, so $2R$ is a better bound.

Comment: @Clayton Draw the circle of radius $R$ and the right triangle whose hypotenuse is the segment from $R$ to $z$.  You should be able to see that the angle the segment makes with the real axis is bounded below by $\pi/4$..

Comment: Okay, so I have worked through your solution just fine until the last bit. Why do we care that $|f(z)|\leq\frac{3R}{|z^2-R^2|}$? Since $z$ can be real, this just says that $|f(z)|$ is bounded above by $\infty$ as far as I can tell. Did I miss something?

Comment: @Clayton It looks like I wasn't clear about that.  See my edited answer.

Answer (score 16):

Let $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n z^n$ be the Taylor expansion of $f(z)$. Also denote $a_{-1}=a_{-2}=0$. By definition,
$$a_n=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{|z|=R}\frac{f(z)}{z^{n+1}}dz,\quad\forall n\ge -2,\, \forall R>0.\tag{1}$$

Note that $\mathrm{Im} (z)=\frac{z-\bar{z}}{2i}$, so when $|z|=R$, 
$$\mathrm{Im} (z)=\frac{z-\frac{R^2}{z}}{2i}.\tag{2}$$
Substituting  $(2)$ into $(1)$, we have
$$a_{n-1}-R^2 a_{n+1}=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{|z|=R}\frac{\mathrm{Im} (z)\cdot f(z)}{z^{n+1}}dz,\quad\forall n\ge -1,\, \forall R>0.\tag{3}$$
By the assumption of $f$ and continuity, $|\mathrm{Im} (z)\cdot f(z)|\le 1$ on $\mathbb{C}$. Then from $(3)$ we know
$$|a_{n-1}-R^2a_{n+1}|\le \frac{2}{R^n},\quad\forall n\ge -1,\, \forall R>0.\tag{4}$$

Given $n\ge -1$, dividing both sides of $(4)$ by $R^2$ and letting $R\to \infty$, we have $a_{n+1}=0$. Therefore, all the coefficients of the Taylor expansion of $f$ are $0$, i.e. $f\equiv 0$.

Comment: Nice, but do you really need induction? Letting $R\to\infty$ in (4) immediately gives $a_{n+1}=0$ and $a_{n-1}=0$.

Comment: @user75064: Yes, you are right. Thank you!

Comment: @user75064: I have edited my answer based on your suggestion. Thank you again.

Comment: I'm really not sure I follow the steps to $(3)$. Could you elaborate just a little? Thanks.

Comment: @Clayton, when $|z|=R$, by $(2)$,  $\frac{1}{\pi}\frac{\mathrm{Im} (z)\cdot f(z)}{z^{n+1}}=\frac{1}{2\pi i}(\frac{f(z)}{z^{n}}-\frac{R^2f(z)}{z^{n+2}})$. Integrating both sides over the circle $|z|=R$, $(3)$ follows from $(1)$.

Comment: Ah, I see now! Thank you!

Comment: @Clayton: You are welcome!

Comment: @Clayton: Thank you for your bounty award! I have to admit that I have no idea to find an approach with your original thoughts. Moreover, I think 75064's approach with Jensen's formula is more widely applied, and with some simplification, Brian's argument gives the simplest proof(the simplification was given in Giraffe's comment, i.e. when $|z|=R$, $z\bar{z}=R^2$, so $|z^2-R^2||f(z)|=2R|\mathrm{Im}(z)||f(z)|\le 2R$).

Comment: @Landscape: I know your proof didn't use my ideas exactly, but I didn't see any reason for the bounty to go to waste. Your approach seemed most direct, so I liked it. I'm still thinking on how to solve it using my original thoughts. I went to a professor and his thoughts matched mine identically up to this point, at which he got stuck as well.

Comment: @Clayton: I am not sure if this way is promising but I am glad to see if you can finally work it out. Please share with us, say post another answer here, once you succeed.

Answer (score 14):

"Me too!" Fix an arbitrary $a\in \mathbb R$. By [Jensen's inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%27s_formula) for every $r>0$ we have 
$$\begin{split} 2\pi \log|f(a)| &\le \int_0^{2\pi} \log|f(a+re^{it})|\,dt \le 
\int_0^{2\pi} \log(|r\sin t|^{-1})\,dt \\ &=  -2\pi\log r- \int_0^{2\pi} \log(|\sin t|)\,dt \end{split}$$
The integral on the right is finite, because $ \log |x|$ is integrable near $0$. Let $r\to \infty$ to conclude $f(a)=0$. Since $f$ vanishes on $\mathbb R$, it vanishes identically.

---

By the way, this works equally well for bounds like  $|f(z)|\le 1/|\mathrm{Im}\,z|^{N}$ or even $|f(z)|\le \exp( 1/|\mathrm{Im}\,z|^{1-\epsilon})-1$. Fails with the assumption $|f(z)|\le \exp( 1/|\mathrm{Im}\,z|)-1$, probably for a good reason.

Comment: Probably the next thing I'll attempt will be showing it for the exponential bound. Thanks!

Comment: This is nice, yet the "...because $\,\log|x|\,$ is integrable near zero" part is a little shaky, unless the OP knows this: $$\lim_{\epsilon\to 0^+}\int\limits_e^a\log x\,dx=\lim_{\epsilon\to 0}\left.\left(x\log x-x\right)\right|_\epsilon^a=\text{finite}$$ since $\,x\log x\xrightarrow[x\to 0^+]{}0\,$

Comment: @DonAntonio: Thanks, but it seems pretty obvious. I think most calculus II students should be able to show something like that.

Comment: I think you're right, @Clayton . Thanks.

Comment: Nice application of Jensen's.  Two small remarks.  The first integral should have $a + r e^{it}$ instead of $re^{it}$ and in the last expression it should be $-2\pi \log(r)$.

Comment: @WimC Thanks. It's good to have readers/editors around.