# Showing that this function is identically zero

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose that $f$ is an entire function and has the property that for all $z ∈ \mathbb{C} \backslash \mathbb{R}$, $|f(z)| \le |1/|Im(z)|$. I want to show that $f ≡ 0$.

I think I probably want to use Liouville's Theorem to show that $f$ is in fact bounded on on $\mathbb{C}$, and then show that the constant $c$ that $f$ is equal to is actually $0$, but I'm getting lost in showing this.

Any hints or suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure that's correct. Take $f(z)=\frac{1}{\text{Im}(z)}$. It's neither constant nor zero.

Comment: Perhaps it's a good thing I wasn't able to solve this problem then. Thank you!

If you are wondering, the problem was copied directly from #8 in this old final complex analysis exam: https://math.berkeley.edu/sites/default/files/pages/F03_Final_Exam-D.Geba__0.pdf

edit: Actually, isn't your function not entire?

Comment: hmm. on $\mathbb{C}$? no. on the other hand $\Im(z)=0\Leftrightarrow z\in\mathbb{R}$ and it's outside of your domain.

Comment: @DanisFischer But your choice for $f$ isn't entire is it?

Comment: This question has already been posted. It found several answers at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/377782/application-of-liouvilles-theorem?rq=1 The key to one solution is Jensen's inequality for entire functions.

Answer (score 1):

On the lines $z=i$ and $z=-i$ we have $|f(z)|\leq 1 $ hence from Hadamard Three Lines Theorem $|f(z)|\leq 1 $ on whole strip $|\mbox{Im}(z) |\leq 1 .$ If $|\mbox{Im}(z) |\geq 1 $ then $|f(z)|\leq \frac{1}{|\mbox{Im}(z) |}\leq 1$ hence $f$ is bounded on whole plane.

Comment: Hadamard three-lines theorem requires boundedness of $f(x)$ on the strip $-1 \leq \operatorname{Im} z \leq 1$

Comment: Yes, you,re right.

Comment: I've never heard of this theorem -- Perhaps I don't yet have the machinery I need to solve this, then. Thanks for the input, though.

Answer (score 0):

If, $|f(z)|\leq \frac{1}{|\mbox{Im}(z) |}$ then $|\frac{1}{f(z) }| \leq |z|.$ Hence $\frac{1}{f(z)}  =az$ but this is impossible. So $f$ must be identicaly zero.

Comment: How do you get $|\frac{1}{f(z) }| \leq |z|?$

Comment: $|\frac{1}{f(z) }| \leq |\mbox{Im}(z)| \leq |z|.$

Comment: In my opinion, it should read $\frac {1}{|f(z)|}\geq |\mbox{Im}(z) |$