# An entire function satisfying some constraint must be zero

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose $f$ is an entire function such that $|f(z)|\,|\Im(z)|^2\leq 1$. Then $f$ is identically zero.

Comment: Some things I have thought that are mostly unconclusive: Plugging $w=iz$ one gets $|f(iz)|\,|\Re(z)|^2\leq 1$. I tried to combine these two bounds to get one for $f$, unsuccesfully. In hindsight, this is a stupid thing to do since there are non-entire, non-bounded functions satisfying the constraint.

Comment: Trying to classify the singularity at infinity: no clue how to do this, since I only control how the function behaves on horizontal lines.

Comment: Trying to use the averaging property of harmonic functions: this may work but it would have to involve a certain amount of clever geometric trickery.

Comment: One thing that particularly bugs me is the fact that $\Im(z)$ appears squared. I don't immediately see how that helps one to have more control over $f$, and I don't know if the result holds if we drop that exponent or not.

Comment: Are you sure about this theorem? Does the constant function $f(z) = c$ with $0<|c|<1$ not fulfil the requirements?

Comment: @Ranc: It does not. The bound tells you that $f$ goes to zero on every vertical line, so if we knew $f$ was constant then it would have to be zero.

Comment: @FM, I now notice this is $\Im (z)$ and not $\Im (f(z))$.

Comment: Have a look at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/377782 (this is for $|\operatorname{Im}(z)|$, not $|\operatorname{Im}(z)|^2$, but the answers still apply.

Comment: @FM It seems mrf's comment resolves your question. Do you agree?