# Entire function satisfying $\left| f \right| \left| Im(z)\right|^2 \leq 1$ is zero

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f$ be an entire function such that $\left| f \right| \left| Im(z)\right|^2 \leq 1$ then show that $f(z) \equiv 0$.

Liouville's theorem does the job, if I can show that $\left| f \right|$ is bounded. The function is bounded in each strip $\left|Im(z)\right| > C$ but I don't know how that implies that the function is bounded on the whole plane.

Comment: One way of seeing this is by arguing that $f \equiv 0$ on $\mathbb{R}$. Use the fact that $\log |f|$ is subharmonic and apply sub mean-value property for circles with centre on real axis and let the radius go to $\infty$ (if you are not familiar with sub mean-value property then you may also use [Jensen's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%27s_formula#:~:text=In%20the%20mathematical%20field%20known,the%20study%20of%20entire%20functions.))

Comment: Have a look at https://math.stackexchange.com/q/377782/42969. That is about $\left| f \right| \left| Im(z)\right| \leq 1$ but the same approach should work.