Analytic function bounded by real part is constant
The following question was part of the 2023 Mathematical Tripos.

Let $h : \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$ be an analytic function. Show that if $\left|h(z)\right| \leq \left| \text{Re}(z) \right|^{-1/2}$ for all $z \in \mathbb{C}$, then $h$ is constant.

First, it is easy to see that if $h$ is constant, it is actually $0$.
By Liouville it suffices to show that $\left| h \right|$ is a bounded function or equivalently that the image of $h$ is not dense in $\mathbb{C}$. However, close to the imaginary axis $\left| \text{Re}(z) \right|^{-1/2}$ blows up and I do not quite see how to bound $\left| h \right|$ in that region.
Any help is greatly appreciated!

https://math.stackexchange.com/q/377782/42969 can be applied to $f(z) = h(iz)^2$. I think this can be closed as a duplicate.
